# creating fixtures without connecting to db

Tags: django, fixtures

I have a setup like this:

- One computer with a python script which collects statistical data
- Another with a django app with models representing the data
- I cannot connect the two computers at all for reasons I can't explain nor are relevant
- I can however, pass the information manually using a disk-on-key once a day

Now I serailze the data using Pickle, and when I upload it to app I just load it and loop. This is working, but I would like to use a functionality similar to `manage.py loaddata fixtures.json` which I used once when migrating a database.

The added bonus of fixtures is:

1. Faster
2. If an error occurs it doesn't save anything to the db (instead of my loop which in a case of error will stop halfway...)

As far as I know, to create fixtures you need some connection to the db (because they include pk which is an auto incremented field and the values depend on those already in db).

Any suggestions?